# Retrofit response is a html code

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working with retrofit 2 for connecting to web service on android studio 3.0 and i have a like request like this

```
@POST("clip/clipmobile/action/clike/clipId/{id}/token/{token}/app/21")
Call<ResponseBody> likeRequest(
    @Path("id") String id,
    @Path("token") String token);
```

and i my retrofit init:

```
 retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(RetrofitInterface.class);
```

and getClient() method :

```
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
```

request on postman is fine but in android resposne.body().string() gets a html code like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fa" lang="fa" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>
        نشر دیجیتال :: default    </title>
    <meta name="samandehi" content="456331049" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://ndigi.ir/images/File/nashr-hamrah-logo.ico" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="{currLang}" /> -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="pear, php, framework, cms, content management" />
    <meta name="description" content="Coming soon to a webserver near you." />
    <meta name="rating" content="General" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="madeby" content="Made by Artimanstudio" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />        <meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow" />    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> -->

    <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) 2008 نشر دیجیتال" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="fa_IR" />
    <meta property="og:title" content=" نان و نمک" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="نان و نمک" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

Comment: yes fine , then what is the problem you facing and what you tried for that

Comment: @Thunder i expect to give me a json to render it

Comment: yes , thats from your Backend , you need to check with your Backend Team member who write this API , right now this api is not returning the response as JSON so you are not getting

Comment: @Thunder but on post man it gave me a json requests stil its from my back end???

Comment: ok got it ,are you missing passing application/json in headers

Comment: @Thunder thank you it works fine

Comment: alright welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add the `accept` header of `application/json` to your request. postman usually adds in `accept:"*/*"` header. Can see this by opening up 'Show Postman Console' in postman then running your request

i.e.

```
@POST("clip/clipmobile/action/clike/clipId/{id}/token/{token}/app/21")
Call<ResponseBody> likeRequest(
    @Header("accept") String type,
    @Path("id") String id,
    @Path("token") String token);
```

then call

```
likeRequest("application/json", id, token)
```